# QGIS : strange tiedpoints after makeGraph

Tags: qgis, dijkstra

I try to use the Dijkstra shortest length path calculation.

On the following program, when I use the Network.shp file (found here : https://geospatialpython.googlecode.com/svn/network.zip) with  `pStart = QgsPoint(-0.8095638694, -0.1578175511)` and `pStop = QgsPoint(0.8907435677, 0.4430834924)`, the value of tiedPoints is [(-0.814696,-0.121406), (0.880931,0.394498)], so OK. (CRS = WGS 84)

When I just change the Shapefile  to "routeToulouse.shp" and the pStart and pStop coordinates to `pStart = QgsPoint(572777,6277751)` and `pStop = QgsPoint(571644,6279403)`  (CRS = RGF93 / Lambert-93), I got this for tiedPoints : 
`[(9999,-7.23497e-310), (9999,-7.23497e-310)]`

Why do I have this strange values?

I use QGIS Desktop to draw the "routeToulouse.shp" file and the 2 points and you can see that the 2 points are on the extent of the map, not outside.

[image]

Here's the source code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.networkanalysis import *
import os,sys

class MapViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
        canvas.useImageToRender(False)
        canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)
        layer = QgsVectorLayer("routeToulouse.shp", "layer1", "ogr")
        #layer = QgsVectorLayer("Network.shp", "layer1", "ogr")
        if not layer.isValid():
            raise IOError("Invalid shapefile")
        director = QgsLineVectorLayerDirector(layer, -1, '', '', '', 3)
        properter = QgsDistanceArcProperter()
        director.addProperter(properter)
        crs = layer.crs()
        print crs.description()
        builder = QgsGraphBuilder(crs)
        pStart = QgsPoint(572777,6277751)    #1.42510,43.58740,572777.082,6277751.358
        pStop = QgsPoint(571644,6279403)   #1.41067,43.60206,571644.110,6279403.609
        #pStart = QgsPoint(-0.8095638694, -0.1578175511)
        #pStop = QgsPoint(0.8907435677, 0.4430834924)
        tiedPoints = director.makeGraph(builder, [pStart, pStop])
        print tiedPoints
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
        layerExtend = layer.extent()
        canvas.setExtent(layerExtend)
        canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer)])
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(canvas)
        contents = QWidget()
        contents.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(contents)
        canvas.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(os.environ['QGIS_PREFIX'], True)
    QgsApplication.initQgis()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.processEvents()
    frame = MapViewer()
    frame.show()
    app.exec_()
```